# Laravel Reservation Form not Mailing

Tags: php, laravel-5.6

I have a 'contact' and 'reservation' form on a client site. The 'contact' form works well and when filled out, it sends the email to my mailtrap.io account. As far as I can see the structure of my 'reservation' form and controller is exactly the same as that of the 'contact form', however, no emails are sent out when the 'reservation' form is filled out. I can't figure out why.

**When I dd the data on both the 'contact' and 'reservation' forms, I can see the array results**. However, as mentioned, the emails for the 'reservation' form is not being sent to mailtrap.io.

Here's my web.php file

```
Route::get('reservation', 'PageController@reservation');
Route::post('reservation', 'PageController@postReservation');
Route::get('contact', 'PageController@contact');
Route::post('contact', 'PageController@postContact');
```

Here's my Controller for both the 'contact' and 'reservation' form. The contact and reservation functions are in the same controller:

```
public function reservation()
{
    return view('reservation');
}

public function postReservation(Request $request)
{
    dd($request->all()); //-> Fill in data to test if form works
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|string|min:2',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'phone' => 'required|digits:10',
        'date' => 'required|date_format:Y/m/d|after:today',
        'seats' => 'required|integer',
        'message' => 'min:10'
    ]);

    $data = array (
        'name' => $request->name,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'phone' => $request->phone,
        'date' => $request->date,
        'time' => $request->time,
        'seats' => $request->seats,
        'reservationMessage' => $request->message,
    );

    Mail::send('emails.reservation', $data, function ($message) use ($data) {
        $message->from('contact@venueat50.co.za');
        $message->to('info@webdevpro.co.za');
        $message->subject($data['name']);
    });

    return redirect('reservation')->with('success', 'Thank you. We will contact you to confirm the booking');
}

public function contact()
{
    return view ('contact');
}

public function postContact(Request $request)
{
    dd($request->all()); //-> Fill in data to test if form works
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|string|min:2',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'number' => 'required|digits:10',
        'subject' => 'required|min:3',
        'message' => 'required|min:10'
    ]);

    $data = array(
        'name' => $request->name,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'number' => $request->number,
        'subject' => $request->subject,
        'bodyMessage' => $request->message
    );

    Mail::send('emails.contact', $data, function($message) use ($data) {
        $message->from('contact@venueat50.co.za');
        $message->to('info@webdevpro.co.za');
        $message->subject($data['subject']);
    });

    return redirect('contact')->with('success', 'Your message has been sent. We will reply promptly');
}
```

I also have an email template setup for both the 'contact' and 'reservation' form. Not sure if that is needed.

Let me also attach the 'contact' and reservation forms:

Contact Form:

```
<form method="post" id="contact-form" action='{{ action('PageController@postContact') }}'>


{{ csrf_field() }}
    @if (session('success'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            {{ session('success') }}
        </div>
    @endif
    <label>Name</label>
    @if($errors->has('name'))
        <small class="form-text invalid-feedback">{{ $errors->first('name') }}</small>
    @endif
    <p><input type="text" name="name" class="reservation-fields" value="{{ old('name') }}"/></p>
    <label>Email</label>
    @if($errors->has('email'))
        <small class="form-text invalid-feedback">{{ $errors->first('email') }}</small>
    @endif
    <p><input type="text" name="email" class="reservation-fields" value="{{ old('email') }}"/></p>
    <label>Mobile Nr</label>
    @if($errors->has('number'))
        <small class="form-text invalid-feedback">{{ $errors->first('number') }}</small>
    @endif
    <p><input type="text" name="number" class="reservation-fields" value="{{ old('number') }}"/></p>
    <label>Subject</label>
    @if($errors->has('subject'))
        <small class="form-text invalid-feedback">{{ $errors->first('subject') }}</small>
    @endif
    <p><input type="text" name="subject" class="reservation-fields" value="{{ old('subject') }}"/></p>
    <label>Message</label>
    @if($errors->has('message'))
        <small class="form-text invalid-feedback">{{ $errors->first('message') }}</small>
    @endif
    <p> <textarea name="message" id="msg-contact" class="reservation-fields" rows="7"></textarea></p>
    <p class="antispam">Leave this empty: <input type="text" name="url" /></p>
    <p class="contact-btn"><input type="submit" value="Send message" id="submit"/></p>
```

And Lastly the Reservation Form:

```
<form method="post" id="reservation-form" action={{ action('PageController@postReservation') }}>
{{ @csrf_field() }}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label>Name*</label>
        <p><input type="text" name="name" class="reservation-fields" required/></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label>Email*</label>
        <p><input type="text" name="email" class="reservation-fields" required/></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label>Phone*</label>
        <p><input type="text" name="phone" class="reservation-fields" required/></p>
    </div>
</div>
<!--end row-->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label>Date*</label>
        <p><input type="date" name="datepicker" id="datepicker" class="reservation-fields" size="30" required/></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label>Time*</label>
        <p>
            <select name="time" class="reservation-fields" >
                <option value="10:00">10:00</option>
                <option value="11:00">11:00</option>
                <option value="12:00">12:00</option>
                <option value="13:00">13:00</option>
                <option value="14:00">14:00</option>
                <option value="15:00">15:00</option>
                <option value="16:00">16:00</option>
            </select>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label>Seats*</label>
        <p><input type="text" name="seats" class="reservation-fields" required/></p>
    </div>
</div>
<!--end row-->
<label>Special Requests</label>
<p> <textarea name="message" id="message2" class="reservation-fields" cols="100" rows="4" tabindex="4"></textarea></p>
<p class="antispam">Leave this empty: <input type="text" name="url" /></p>
<p class="alignc"><input type="submit" value="Book Now" id="submit" /></p>
```

Comment: are there same emails being used when testing both forms? And are they both set in mailtrap.io whitelist?

Comment: Well, the Mail functionalities is setup in the .env file. The .env is configured for Mailtrap (i.e. mailtrap username and password). So it should not matter what ->to email address I use. As can be seen in the controller, both are ->to and ->from addresses are the same

Comment: Did you left uncommented  `dd()` function on purpose?    
`dd($request->all()); //-> Fill in data to test if form works`

Comment: Just for the example yes. I obviously comment it out when I test the functionality